# Change URI Trigger for EE 2.0 Pagination

Tags: pagination, expressionengine

Currently the pagination works like /P1 /P2 /P3. I would like to change it to something like /page-1 /page-2 /page-3. Does anyone know of a simple plugin or even how I could change any code to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this on line 2879 of mod.channel.php in a recent release of EE2:

```
 if (preg_match("#^P(\d+)|/P(\d+)#", $this->query_string, $match))
```

Do with that what you will.

If it was me, and if there was any chance that I'd want to upgrade, package, or brag about the EE install, I'd probably try to build an addon for this. There is already [a hook that might help](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel_module_create_pagination). If that hook isn't up to the job, you may have to hack; and the best hack is a hook and a feature request. Good luck!